# How to relate one table with many other tables in Ms access?

Tags: ms-access

The database i'm trying to create have four tables. tblPatient information, tblparasitology tests, tblserology tests and tblbiochemical tests. All the later three tables are related to patient information table. What i want to ask is that, is there a problem if i use the primary key in the table patient information to foreign keys of all the other tables? in other words how many tables (foreign keys) can be related to a primary key on one table?

Answer (score 0):

There is really no practical or particular limit here.

however one tip, one concept to keep in mind?

While you can setup all these related tables, to create forms that edit the data?

Each form is STILL based on the one base table.

So you can create a form based on tblPatients.

So allow view and editing and adding of say tblserology results?
That will become a sub form. NOTE VERY careful here that the form tblPaitent is based ONLY on that one table. And the child table (and child form (ie: sub form) tblserology will ONLY be based on tblserology table. So the forms to hook up, wire up the relatonships between the tables are STILL only based on the single table.

To allow editing of related data, you thus use sub forms. If you do this correctly, then no code is required to edit and display and maintain say display of test results for a given patient.

So each and all tables will have a primary key (auto number id).
To realate a child table back up to a parent table, you create a plane jane long number column. This value will be automatic setup for you if you follow the above advice for a main form, and then a sub-form for the child table data.

Comment: So, The tables relationship is one to many, The patient ID number is the primary key that is related to foreign keys on each of the other three tables then I'm creating a form based on tbl patient information and add three sub forms for the other tables. What did I miss?

Comment: 100% right on the money here. Many make the mistake of building some query that joins in the child tables and then try to create a form based on that that query. Create the 3 forms - each form is based on their respective table. Then with the main form in design mode, drag + drop in a child form onto that form in design mode from the nav pain. The sub form can (will likely) be a continues item form to display the child rows in a type of grid. You can then add additonal rows, or say have a button row click to display a detail edit the one row as non continues form.

Comment: Thank you very much